# Optimal solution to extend a python list by adding the at the beginning of the list instead of tail?

Tags: python, performance, list

You have

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

And want to insert list `y` at the beginning of `x`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

What is the optimal solution to do this in Python?

Comment: What's wrong with `x = y + x`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = y + x
```

This simple solution runs twice as fast as the solution with `deque` for smaller input sizes:

```
$ cat x1.py 
for i in range(1000000):
    x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    y = [1, 2, 3]
    x = y + x

$ cat x2.py 
from collections import deque
for i in range(1000000):
    d = deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    d.extendleft(reversed([1, 2, 3]))

$ time python x1.py

real    0m1.912s
user    0m1.864s
sys     0m0.040s

$ time python x2.py

real    0m5.368s
user    0m5.316s
sys     0m0.052s
```

However, it becomes slower for larger sizes of input:

```
>python -m timeit -s "y = range(100000)" "x = list(xrange(10000000)); y+x"
10 loops, best of 3: 229 msec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "from collections import deque; y = range(100000)" "d = deque(xrange(10000000)); d.extendleft(reversed(y))"
10 loops, best of 3: 178 msec per loop
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the first benchmark does not just test the `appendleft` method but the time incurred from importing `collections`, creating a deque (which requires a list literal) vs creating a list literal, and calling `reversed`. So IMHO this is *not* a good comparison.

Answer (score 22):

```
x[0:0] = y
```

- notationally simple
- performance characteristics: *unknown*
- preserves id(x)

Comment: Been using Python daily for 3 years and I never knew you could assign to a list slice. Every day I learn a new Python feature. And yet... "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Answer (score 18):

When you want to append on the left, a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is much more efficient than a list. Use the `extendleft` method.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> d.extendleft(reversed([1, 2, 3]))
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

If you always append on the left *only*, consider keeping the elements in a list in reverse order.

Comment: If `y = [1, 2, 3]` is long, is this still optimal? As you're then reversing a huge list.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: `reversed` returns a reverse iterator instead of constructing a reversed list. Space complexity is O(`len(y)`) for the entire operation, but only O(1) for `reversed`.

Comment: @larsmans a simple `x=y+x` is taking almost half time than your code.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: you are right; I have checked it: `real 0m1.912s` against `real    0m5.368s`; that is even more than twice

Comment: @jamylak: ok, you are right, when the array is big enough `deque` is better; but when the array is not so big x+y is better; take a look at this: http://ideone.com/eMyUW and http://ideone.com/WGeIw

Comment: @IgorChubin I agree but note that those tests are not fair since that includes the initial import time.

Comment: @jamylak you're creating a list from a range in `foo` that's why foo is taking more time than `foo2`.

Comment: @jamylak: 4 sec for import? no, that is a little bit too much :) I think that the result depends on the relation `(number of iterations)/(size of list)`. That is the main point.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That is not the reason, both the list and dequeue are created the same way to make sure that is fair.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You are missing the point, doing it that way is not testing the speed of putting `y` at the front. You are also testing how long it takes to create the list/deque but we are assuming that they are already existing and seeing what is the fastest way to add a list at the beginning. Not the fastest way to create a list and then add it to the beginning.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: add one 0 to `y = range(100000000)` and you will feel the difference ;)
`

Comment: @IgorChubin Yes I understand but you should definitely leave imports in the setup if you are going to do timings.

Answer (score 10):

Depending what you are doing with the result, perhaps you don't want to make a list at all:

```
new_x = itertools.chain(y, x)
```

Now you have an iterator that will produce all the values in y, and then all the values in x.  Now you can iterate it:

```
for val in new_x:
    blah blah
```